# TFS 2012 Install fails on SQL configuration. TF400711

Tags: sql, tfs

Im installing TFS 2012 on a windows Server 2012 VM. Im using a single server configuration and have SQL server standard installed. When I go through the TFS setup wizard it hangs on creating the database and after an hour or so I get the error below.

TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Team Foundation databases: TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step Update Servicing Resources for component UpdateTfsServicingResources during Install: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct.. For more information, see the configuration log.

You can view my log here:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ioN5Ats0NlY1AzYjRJR19wck0/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

Comment: Can you see if the release manifest file is not corrupted? C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools\Deploy\TfsServicingFiles\ReleaseManifest.xml. You seem to have 12gb on the machine so a corrupt download is my current guess.

Comment: That was the problem. Once I deleted those files and started a clean install it worked.

Comment: @Thomas What files did you delete? In what folder? I got stuck in the same place while upgrading do TFS2012, right after ReleaseManifest.xml is loaded.